# What would the minimum and maximum value of int x be in this case?

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm revising for my mid-term exam in concurrent programming in C and I'm stuck on this question.

Say you have the following loop:

```
int x = 20;

for (int i = -3; i <= 7; i++)
    x -= 2;
}
```

On a monoprocessor machine, what are the minimum and maximum values possible for the variable int x after being executed simultaneously by 5 threads?

EDIT : x is of course a shared (global) variable with each thread.

Comment: what difference would it make for a multiprocessor machine?

Comment: I assume that the variable `x` would be a global variable, and the loop would execute in each and every thread? If that is so, then you should probably mention it in the question as it's very relevant to the problem at hand. And of course tell us what ***you*** think the answer is, and *why*.

Comment: The question is, at best, completely ambiguous. First, is `x` global?  Static?  Assuming `x` is a global or static variable, it's impossible to tell. It's *undefined behavior*, for one.  And where is it stated that reading or writing an `int` value is atomic?  If accessing the variable isn't atomic, the final value can be a mashup of anything.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Edited the question for clarification. I think the first thread will bring the value of x down to 0 but since they are all working simultaneously the behaviour is not exactly clear. Thats why I asked the question here to make sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behaviour of the program is *undefined* due to the potential for simultaneous read and write to `x`.

Access to `x` needs to be controlled by mutual exclusion, or steps need to be taken to ensure that `x -= 2` is *atomic*. Only then can we talk about the possible values that `x` can take.

Comment: On a uniprocessor machine environment, it is undefined?

Comment: The standard doesn't mention that case, so methinks still yes.

Comment: Sorry, I beg to differ. If I put the above snippet in `main()`, I believe it will have a pretty defined outcome. Please tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes of course it would work if you bunged the above in `int main()`. But it's the "simultaneously" bit I don't like. You'll get unsequenced access to `x`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Lets say two threads are doing the loop. One goes on to read the current value of `x` and then gets preempted. The next thread then does its `x -= 2` and in turn is preempted by the first thread. This uses its value (which is not the current value of `x`) and subtracts 2 and assign it to `x`.

Comment: With simultaneous access from multiple threads, even simple assignment such as `x = 2` would have to be atomic in order to preclude really unpredictable results and not just "missed some of the decrements" that the question seems to be implying would happen.

Comment: My bad, missed the 5 threads part till time, focused on uniprocessor too much. Now this all makes sense.

Comment: I think if we use mutexes for accesses to `x`, the whole question gets rather pointless. The main purpose of that question seems to be to identiy the possible race conditions when decrementing `x`. Otherwise the result after executing the 5 threads is fixed at 20-5*11*2 = -90.

Comment: @Gerardh - if mutexes are not used for access to `x`, the question is even more pointless, since the behaviour is then undefined.

Comment: @Peter: The question seems to be aimed at creating awareness for UB and when & why we need mutexes. If we use mutexes, there is no range of possible values.

Comment: In which case the question may as well be simplified to "Which cat might the compiler eat if it tries to build `int main(){int i; i = ++i;}`?"

Comment: @Gerardh - Someone who is deliberately trying to raise awareness of undefined behaviour would leave the door open for an answer of undefined behaviour - which this question (by asking only for a minimum and maximum value) does not.   So I suspect the question, asked of the OP, is poorly constructed (asked in ignorance).